# Why do I get an infinite loop despite doing a very similar approach?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
  // loop 1, 2 etc
  var primeNums = [];
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    // check if prime
    console.log('i ', i);
    var isNotPrime = false;
    for (var z = 2; z < i; z++) {
      // 7 / 2 is not factor or 7 == 7 prime
      if (i % z == 0 && i != z) {
        isNotPrime = true;
      }
      console.log('z', z, i);
    }
    if (isNotPrime == false) {
      primeNums.push(i)
    }
  }
  console.log(primeNums.reduce((add, current) => {
    return add += current;
  }));
  return primeNums.reduce((add, current) => {
    return add += current;
  });
}

sumPrimes(977);
```

This code has the primeNums and checks every number counting up, for each number it checks every number counting up and checks if it's not a prime, if it is a prime, it pushes the result.

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
  // Helper function to check primality
  function isPrime(num) {
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
      if (num % i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Check all numbers for primality
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i))
      sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

This code checks if a number divided doesn't give a floating number and runs that as a function for every number counting up to num while adding up the prime numbers.

Why do I get a infinite loop in my program?

Mine is the first block of code.

Comment: Did you try debugging it (execute it line by line in a debugger and check all the values) ? What did you find?

Comment: @CherryDT I did, it does exactly as expected, freecodecamp just tells me potential infinite loop after like 100 logs

Comment: where do you define `num`? `for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {` imho here lies the infinite loop issue since you haven't defined num. The example you posted after does (passing it as a variable in the function

Comment: Maybe your code is taking too long to execute

Comment: It is not infinite loop, you just print too much console.log that freecodecamp complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is the second for loop if condition. You are never breaking the loop once the condition is tested true. It is looping to the entire range of the given number

```
      if (i % z == 0 && i != z) {
        isNotPrime = true; // Need break statement after this.
      }
```

As others pointed out It is taking too long to calculate the results.
Optimization we can do for the program

- *All even numbers are not primes except for 2, so you can always increment the for loop by 2, that takes our 50% of the numbers to be calculated*
- *In the second for loop you don't need to check for range of the number instead you can check for the number/2 only*

This is my solution with your code:

```
  var primeNums = [];
function sumPrimes(num) {
  
  for (var i = 3; i < num; i+=2) {
    // check if prime
    console.log('i ', i);
    var isNotPrime = false;
    for (var z = 2; z < i/2; z++) {
      // 7 / 2 is not factor or 7 == 7 prime
      if (i % z == 0 && i != z) {
        isNotPrime = true;
        break;
      }
      console.log('z', z, i);
    }
    if (isNotPrime == false) {
      primeNums.push(i)
    }
  }
  console.log(primeNums.reduce((add, current) => {
    return add += current;
  })+2);
  return primeNums.reduce((add, current) => {
    return add += current;
  }) + 2; // Add extra 2 since initial 2 is removed.
  
}

sumPrimes(977);
```